# Why am I getting strange results when generating Random() numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

My program needs to:

a. Generate an array of 20 random integers from zero to nine. Search for the first occurrence, if any, of the number 7, and report its position in the array.

b. Repeat the computation of part a 1000 times, and for each position in the array, report the   number of times that the first occurrence of a 7 in the array is at that position

However whenever I run the program I get strange results (different every time) such as:

1. No sevens found at any position
2. 1000 sevens found at one position and no sevens found anywhere else
3. Hundreds of sevens found in 2 positions, and none found anywhere else.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my program?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Week_6_Project_2
    {
    class Program
    {

    static int intArrayLength = 20;
    static int[] resultsArray = new int[intArrayLength];

    public static Array generateRandomArray() {
        int[] randomNumberArray = new int[intArrayLength];
        Random random = new Random();
        int popcounter = 0;
        while (popcounter < intArrayLength) {
            randomNumberArray[popcounter] = random.Next(0, 10);
            popcounter += 1;
        }
        return randomNumberArray;
    }

    public static void searchForSevens()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int[] randomArray = (int[])generateRandomArray();
        while (counter < intArrayLength)
        {
            if (randomArray[counter] == 7)
            {
                resultsArray[counter] += 1;
                counter = intArrayLength;
            }
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int searchCounter = 0;
        while (searchCounter < 1000)
        {
            searchForSevens();
            searchCounter += 1;
        }

        int displayCounter = 0;
        while (displayCounter < intArrayLength)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of first occurrence of 7 at position {0} = {1}", displayCounter, resultsArray[displayCounter]);
            displayCounter += 1;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: `Week_6_Project_2`: So you want us fix your homework?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: You need to use a single instance of Random class. You are creating many instances in while loop.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I kind of makes sense in this case, considering he wants to create new sequence every time.

Comment: @Euphoric Not really. What's the difference between random numbers generated by one random generator or several, properly initialized ones? If it's a good RNG there shouldn't be. Just make one and be done with it.

Comment: @Euphoric NO - there is seldom any reason for anyone to have multiple instances of Random class.  Ever.

Comment: @Euphoric  That's not how it works.  If you want a new sequence every time, the best way is to use the same `Random` object, but just continue it after the numbers you've already used.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Actually reusing same random for different sequences compromises "statistical randomness" of each sequence. So reusing same sequence is the wrong way.

Comment: @Euphoric No, it really does not.  If the sequence is presumed to be random in the first place, then it is still random when you *extend* it.  (pseudo)Random sequences are not more random if you use less of them.  Note that this is *not* the same as re-using the sequence.  You are re-using the object, but you are *extending* the sequence.  It's just as random as it ever was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem is that each `searchForSevens()` test only takes a small fraction of time and the Random class uses auto-seeding from the clock. The clock however has a limited resolution. The result is that many (sometimes all) of your random sequences will be the same. And at most you will have 2 or 3 different result sets.

The simple fix for this single-threaded program is to use 1 static instance of Random.

Comment: Thanks! I removed "Random random = new Random();" from "generateRandomArray();". I then placed "static Random random = new Random();" with the other static variables. The program now works correctly.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - that will not produce any better or even different results.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell what do you think NewGuid() uses to get random numbers? :)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor Probably a cryptographically secure RNG. But I believe Microsoft goes to great lengths document that "Guids are not random". In my totally unqualified opinion, seeding with `Guid.NewGuid*().GetHashCode()` is likely to give you different results if two copies of `Program.exe` started at the exact same time but, thanks to the Pigeonhole principle, you run the risk of generating two different `Guid` objects with the same hash code. So you're susceptible to the same problem.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - that still does not ask for a Guid. A simple incrementing counter would be enough as a seed. Or one thread-safe shared master Random.

Answer (score 3):

You're instantiating a new instance of `Random` every time you call the `generateRandomArray` method. Since the random number generator uses the current time as a seed, instantiating two `Random` instances at the same time results in the same numbers being generated, which explains your unexpected results.

To solve your problem, you should only instantiate one `Random` instance, store it in private field, and reuse it every time you call the `Next` method.

Comment: But what if he wants to check "histogram" of sequences the random generates. That would require creating new Random every time.

Comment: @Euphoric - no it wouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I assume stems from the fact, that `Random()` uses current time as seed. And the computation happens so fast, that each time `new Random()` is called, it uses same time. So you get same sequence of numbers.

To fix this, you simply need to set seed by yourself, incremmenting it every cycle should be enough.

```
long base = DateTime.Now.TotalMilliseconds;
Random rand = new Random(base+searchCounter);
```

.. something like that.

Comment: -1 Too complicated. To fix this you simply need to make one instance.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Is this the only reason to downvote? Just for it is `Too complicated` (BTW: I think it is only complicated for you)

Comment: *@ta.speot.is Is this the only reason to downvote? Just for it is Too complicated (BTW: I think it is only complicated for you) – L.B 6 mins ago* No, other people should downvote it for using DateTime.Now.TotalMilliseconds which can decrement while searchCounter increments leading you to reseed with the same value. Note: this problem only exists because the solution is too complicated.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Just to explain. base is supposed to be initialized outside the loop. So nothing will decrease.

Comment: If you're going to initialise something outsode of the loop ... initialise one instance of `Random`. Why complicate things?

Answer (score -1):

I will not answer but will try to give an analogy for the people that think that they need more then one Random instance...

Suppose that you need to fill 6 sheets of paper with random numbers from 1-6.  Ask yourself this: do you need 6 dices or one to do the job?  If you answer that you need more than one dice, ask yourself this: how different or more random is throwing different dice instead of same dice every time?

I mean, if you throw ONE on a dice, next throw of a dice won't have any less chance to be ONE again than it would be any other number.  It goes against intuition, but it is mathematically and statistically so.

Comment: The reasons for multiple instances are ususally not "better randomness" but easier resource management and thread-safety. It is attractive, that's why this question pops up so often.

Comment: I only admit that using it in threaded environments would justify multiple instances...

Answer (score -2):

In your original code, you're calling the `Random` method in rapid succession [<sup>[broken example based on OP's original code]</sup>](http://ideone.com/9LQchA), thus seeding the method with the same number, resulting in duplicate "random" numbers. Creating a static member will ensure randomness simply because you're only creating a single instance of it.

Try creating a single static instance of `random` like this. [<sup>[static member example]</sup>](http://ideone.com/MrIZTO).

```
static readonly Random Random = new Random();
```

Based on this, here's how I would solve your particular problem.

```
using System;

namespace Week_6_Project_2
{
    class Program
    {
        // ******************************************
        // THIS IS A SINGLE INSTANCE OF Random.
        // read below as to why I'm seeding the instantiation of Random();
        static readonly Random Random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        // ******************************************

        private const int IntArrayLength = 20;
        static readonly int[] ResultsArray = new int[IntArrayLength];

        public static Array GenerateRandomArray()
        {
            var randomNumberArray = new int[IntArrayLength];

            var popcounter = 0;
            while (popcounter < IntArrayLength)
            {
                randomNumberArray[popcounter] = Random.Next(0, 10);
                popcounter += 1;
            }
            return randomNumberArray;
        }

        public static void SearchForSevens()
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var randomArray = (int[])GenerateRandomArray();
            while (counter < IntArrayLength)
            {
                if (randomArray[counter] == 7)
                {
                    ResultsArray[counter] += 1;
                    counter = IntArrayLength;
                }
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            var searchCounter = 0;
            while (searchCounter < 1000)
            {
                SearchForSevens();
                searchCounter += 1;
            }

            var displayCounter = 0;
            while (displayCounter < IntArrayLength)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of first occurrence of 7 at position {0} = {1}", displayCounter, ResultsArray[displayCounter]);
                displayCounter += 1;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

---

***Further reading about `Random()`***

Beyond the answer above, sometimes it is necessary to seed `Random(int);` (I like to use the HashCode of a Guid) to ensure further randomness. This is because the default seed uses the clock which from the docs [<sup>[microsoft]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) has a finite resolution. If your class is instantiated multiple times in quick succession (< 16ms), you will get the same seed from the clock... this breaks stuff.
[<sup>[example of seeded `Random(int)` run in rapid succession with random results]</sup>](http://ideone.com/kXc8QC)

> "using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers."

**hear me when I say that you should NOT instantiate a new Random on every iteration of a loop -- use a static member**

---

Another valid reason to implement your own seed is when you want to ***recreate*** a random sequence [<sup>[example of two identical lists based on same seed]</sup>](http://ideone.com/DdVmN1). Re-using the same seed will recreate the sequence since the sequence is based on the seed.

*note: others might say that seeding it is not necessary [<sup>[link]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072103/124069), but I personally believe that for  the additional few keystrokes and the microscopic hit on the clock, you might as well increase the probability of a unique seed. It doesn't hurt anything, and in some situations it can help.*

Comment: *It's seeded to increase the randomness* [Relative to what?](http://ideone.com/G5ZQnc).

Comment: This uses and a static instance and a seed, providing 2 solutions (1 disputable) without any clear explanation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Maybe not explaining (which I've done now) doesn't deserve an up-vote in your opinion, and I'd be fine with that. But voting a technically correct answer down is just plain rude. My solution would solve the OP's problem just as well as yours.. oh wait, you didn't leave an example.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I've updated my answer to appease the concern. My comments on seeding are based on the official [MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

Comment: It seems every answer got a downvote here. And an example is not always necessary or useful, especially when it contains lots of irrelevant code. Your main point remains just an opinion, w/o supporting facts.

Comment: Yes, before posting my prev comment.

Comment: @HenkHolterman [here's an example of when seeding works](http://ideone.com/kXc8QC). It's basically the point I was trying to make in my answer.

Comment: Insisting on multiple Random instances is as wrong as it could be.  It misses whole point of getting the knack what random (or even pseudorandom) numbers are.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor who is insisting on it? The point is, if your code generates multiple instances in close succession, you could have issues. Not that one would ever generate multiple instances in a single for loop, but rather that the class could be instantiated multiple times in close succession (within 16ms) causing issues.

Comment: Your edit doesn't address the fact that Guids can have the same hash code. If you have one process create a new Random object without an explicit seed once per second, then none of them will have the same seed. Look at my link, with your Guid hash code algorithm you can generate the same seed several times. It's also worth noting that one Random object per thread is probably good enough for random-like numbers. If you need something closer to "true" random, use RNGCryptoServiceProvider. See [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

Comment: @ta.speot.is, yes they can, but it's less likely than using the built in seed. I'm not forcing a seed on anyone, and in fact, the answer I give solves the problem, and the first code snipped doesn't include a seed at all. I'm only extending the concept to include seeding since it helps more than hurts. Click the links in the answer to see functioning results.

Comment: *but it's less likely than using the built in seed* My original comment was *relative to what?* With specific reference to *If you have one process create a new Random object without an explicit seed once per second, then none of them will have the same seed.*, how is seeding with a Guid's hash code less likely to generate Random objects with the same seed?